# New tag auto-complete is not used for adding favourite / ignored tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, autocomplete

Encountered on the right hand pane whilst looking at unanswered questions. Also encountered on the user page under prefs.

I guess it could be intentional, but I thought I ought to mention it in case it was an oversight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's indeed intentional; [the reasons are three-fold](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuE1jST-hbM#t=0m5s):

1. When you add an interesting/ignored tag, you usually *know* which tag it's going to be.
2. You can also favorite/ignore from the on-hover tag menu, which also contains the tag wiki excerpt.
3. The new tag suggestion list takes up a lot more space, so making it work with the tiny ignored/favorites boxes is harder.

Granted, 3. isn't an unsolvable problem, but with 1. and 2., I don't think it's necessary.