# Toggle favorite tags from "Related Tags" list in sidebar

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, sidebar, related-tags

On any SE site, meta or not, for anybody using tags at all, it is a very useful feature to be able to change tag favorites.

List of questions showing the questions tags provide brilliant support for this by opening the tag wiki excerpt that contains the favorite toggle star:

> [image]

This feature is missing in the "Related Tags" list in the sidebar, when hovering the tags there, no popup opens:

> [image]

I think it would be very useful with related tags to choose new favorites.

Comment: This may already be addressed in [New tag auto-complete is not used for adding favourite / ignored tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101850/new-tag-auto-complete-is-not-used-for-adding-favourite-ignored-tags/101856#101856)

Comment: So you basically want a way to favourite related tags straight from another tag's wiki? Without clicking on the tag and going to its own wiki?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ No, it's about the tags in the list of related tags in the sidebar of a list of questions: some of these are favourites alredy, some are not. It would also work in the list of favourites above that, but to unvafourite only.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I've edited this to make more sense, it's not a dupe indeed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks :) I basically had it in [my original comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260511/toggle-favorite-tags-in-sidebar#comment849394_260511)! ;)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yes, but OP missed your point and focused on some non related stuff instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, upon inspection, that Stack Exchange have purposely stopped the popup from appearing by adding the class `no-tag-menu` to those tags.

It would be very easy to add the popup if they removed this class (I have no idea why they've added it!).

To remove the class (and therefore add the popup back), this simple jQuery code will work:

```
$('.no-tag-menu').removeClass('no-tag-menu');
```

If you want it as a userscript (to automatically do this whenever you visit the page), install it [from GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/b1296d500b48161b2284/raw/3e291b0059ed7e18098c704186293100a6bb129e/addTagPopups.user.js). See [here](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you're unsure on how to install it.

A gif demonstrating it working:

> [image: demonstration gif]